# App crashes while loading a heavy UI layout dynamically

Tags: android, user-interface

I am facing a serious problem. In my Home screen UI, the activity first has to determine the screen size and then it has to dynamically add GUI elements based on that data. To be precise, I have used 13 child relative layout under a parent layout. So you can understand dynamically determining their size and loading image on them take some time. **In high performance device(Galaxy S3), it take around 3 sec to load the data, but in low performance device the app crashes.** I tried to use asynctask, but same thing happened. It would be very helpful if anyone can help on this matter. Code goes as below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    asyncTask = new LoadHome();
    asyncTask.execute();

}

private class LoadHome extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> implements
        OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // initialize the dialog
        pd.setTitle("Loading...");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait while loading...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                int width = display.getWidth();
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                int height = display.getHeight();
                pal = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item1);
                pa = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (width * 0.625),
                        (int) (height * 0.1876));
                pa.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.itemBC);
                pa.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                pa.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.item2);
                pal.setLayoutParams(pa);

                bdnews = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item9);
                bdn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                bdn.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.item8);
                bdn.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item6);
                bdnews.setLayoutParams(bdn);

                ds = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item6);
                star = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.625), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                star.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                star.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item4);
                ds.setLayoutParams(star);

                somokal = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item4);
                sk = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                sk.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                sk.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item3);
                somokal.setLayoutParams(sk);

                fe = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item3);
                fb = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                fb.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                fb.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item1);
                fe.setLayoutParams(fb);

                banglanews = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item7);
                ban = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.3752));
                ban.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item5);
                ban.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                ban.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.item6);
                banglanews.setLayoutParams(ban);

                adesh = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item2);
                amard = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                amard.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                amard.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.itemBC);
                adesh.setLayoutParams(amard);

                kk = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item8);
                kko = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                kko.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                kko.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item6);
                kk.setLayoutParams(kko);

                bbcn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item5);
                bbc = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.625), (int) (height * 0.3752));
                bbc.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                bbc.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item2);
                bbc.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.item3);
                bbcn.setLayoutParams(bbc);

                independent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item10);
                ind = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.625), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                ind.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                ind.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item8);
                independent.setLayoutParams(ind);

                vorerkagoj = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item11);
                vor = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                vor.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                vor.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item7);
                vor.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.item10);
                vorerkagoj.setLayoutParams(vor);

                ittefaq = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item12);
                iff = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.3125), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                iff.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                iff.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item10);
                ittefaq.setLayoutParams(iff);

                jonokontho = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item13);
                jono = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (width * 0.625), (int) (height * 0.1876));
                jono.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                jono.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.item11);
                jono.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.item12);
                jonokontho.setLayoutParams(jono);


                btn0 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.paloimg);
                btn0.setImageResource(R.drawable.palo);

                btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.adimg);
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.amardesh);

                btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.feimg);
                btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fe);

                btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sking);
                btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.somokal);

                btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bbcimg);
                btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.bbc);

                btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dsimg);
                btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.dsbg);

                btn6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.kkimg);
                btn6.setImageResource(R.drawable.kk);

                btn7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bdimg);
                btn7.setImageResource(R.drawable.bdnew);

                btn8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.banglaimg);
                btn8.setImageResource(R.drawable.bangla);

                btn9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.indimg);
                btn9.setImageResource(R.drawable.independent);

                btn10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bdvorerk);
                btn10.setImageResource(R.drawable.vk);

                btn11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bdiff);
                btn11.setImageResource(R.drawable.iff);

                btn12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bdjk);
                btn12.setImageResource(R.drawable.jonokontho);

                infoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aboutBtn);
            }
        });

        return null;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();

        // OnClickListener allocation
        btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn10.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn11.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn12.setOnClickListener(this);


        infoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.dev);
                builder.setTitle("Developer Info");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                String Text1 = "News flash is developed by";
                String Text2 = "TEAM ORANGE JUICE";
                String Text3 = "email: teamoj@gmail.com";
                builder.setMessage(Text1 +"\n"+ Text2 +"\n"+ Text3); 

                builder.setPositiveButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }           
        });

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
        //code goes here which are not included...

        }

    }

}
```

Log:

```
05-04 21:23:41.601: I/ApplicationPackageManager(17393): cscCountry is not German : TML
05-04 21:23:41.773: D/AndroidRuntime(17393): Shutting down VM
05-04 21:23:41.773: W/dalvikvm(17393): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at com.example.decoupled.HomeActivity$LoadHome$1.run(HomeActivity.java:76)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    ... 20 more
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101030e a=-1}
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393):    ... 23 more
```

**Answer:**

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Thats the cause of error in android 2.2
Removed it from XML and it's working like magic now :)
Thanks everyone by the way

Comment: share the logs, It could be OutoFMemory error.

Comment: The way you are using AsyncTask is almost useless. It will have no effect.

Comment: Doing `doInBackground` and then `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {` cancel each other out. You start a thread, and tell that thread to run everything on the main thread. TL;DR: Your async task is doing nothing.

Comment: yeah, I know...but how can I do UI related work here? doInBackground is not under main thread :/

Comment: You just do it normally. Why even have a asynctask? It's not async...

Comment: Tried it normally. It crashes even if I don't use asynctask :/

Comment: @abbas.aniefa Log is shared in the edited post now

Comment: I think it's missing some resource or the resource used is in not the right format ` E/AndroidRuntime(17393): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101030e a=-1} 05-04 21:23:41.796: E/AndroidRuntime(17393): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)`

Comment: Can you post the xml you are trying to update/add to ?

Comment: I guess you don't understand the purpose of AsyncTask well. What is the purpose to use AsyncTask, when you ask the system to run the code on the main thread from that AsyncTask class? It's like scratching left ear with right hand.

Comment: If you set theme in your Activity tag  of your manifest then remove it

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi the thing is if it missed some resource, in Galaxy s3 it should also crash!! But in Galaxy s3, the app doesn't crash...it only take around 3 sec to load the UI :/

Comment: The error is in the binary file line 44 though there is no use of async task .
res folder coukd find some resource or it is not drawable type

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you want to set your layout programmatically based on screen size, when you could just create different layouts based on the same information (ldpi, mdpi, etc.)?

Comment: @MartinHaTh I know, but the thing is smartphones comes in different screen sizes with small differences.
Suppose if the screen size is 320*533, i have to set my first image 200*100. I mean it's necessary for me to calculate this way. So to be pin point perfect, I want to set the layout programmatically

Comment: @user2358769 please post your solution in a different answer and accept it yourself; that way others can identify if the original problem has been solved or not. Editing the question with "Answer" doesn't really help!

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest you some beautiful coding practices so that you can easily keep track of what's messing around:

First of all the code you wrote inside of `runOnUiThread` can easily be re-factored to a method let's say `createDynamicUI` so that your code looks like:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        createDynamicUI();
        });
}
```

I don't see the point of creating the UI from code;you could have done this using XML and it's not dynamic at all;as far as I could get,you meant that you are placing components dynamically this way;but this is same as doing from XML as static,as you see you are simply coding for each of the components;nothing reusable!It would be dynamic and worth to write in code if you had some randomized automated process that create some relative layout and places them where you expect them to see.**And that way you wouldn't even have to write this heavyweight code to take a background thread!**

Now the main point. **AsyncTask** is used to do some large processing works like fetching data over internet while your UI is resting without bothering it! So what you have done has already broken this established order and made the whole system useless!
The solution you have to try is:

1. Use a XML to define the static UI(so far it seems so from your
   code!)
2. Assign `AsyncTask` the data fetching work and when it completes
   update your UI.
3. Meanwhile you should show a progress dialog with
   some cool texts so that your user's not gonna get annoyed! :P

Comment: Dibosh, I think you have not taken a proper look on the code...implementing the UI is certainly possible in XML, and i had done it at the initial stage. But it's not what we want due to different peculiar sizes of mobile(I guess I have already told you that earlier). We will discuss it more when we meet. :D

I don't have any data fetching except updating the UI in the HomeActivity. That's what made the problem weird. I couldn't understand where I should use AsyncTask!!! As the only work in that UI was to determine the layout size and set the images on them

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use layoutInflater?And create your layout programmatically by extends the View class and use that layout in your layoutInflater from your main class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

That's the cause of error in Android 2.2 Removed it from XML and it's working like magic now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take a look how AsyncTask works [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

All calculations or anything you want to run in background should be done in `doInBackground` method. Don't do anything related to UI in this method even with `runOnUiThread`(this is your performance issues)

Update your UI in `onPostExecute` method

Comment: I tried it onPostExecute methos also. The problem is the calculations are related to UI. So I can't even include them in doInBackground. As I said, the app runs fine in high performance device(Galaxy S3), but in low performance device the app crashes. But I want it to run in all device

Comment: Creating some components and adding them to visual tree can not be the purpose of creating an **AsyncTask**. `-1` for `Demones` for giving confusing answer which actually have no base to solve this.